# Coded UI in VS2013 closes the application automatically once test method is completed running

Tags: coded-ui-tests

In visual studio 2013, coded ui closes the application automatically once all test method completed running.

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        uiCommonEE = UICommonEE.GetCommonEE();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void OpenWorkspaceTest()
    {
        uiCommonEE.SetBaseState();

        uiCommonEE.OpenWorkspace("C:\Path\EE_Multmodule_AllDataTypes.eew");

    }
```

I'm launching my application from TestInitialize() Method
once the testmethod is completed running, application gets closed automatically. 
In testcleanuup() and classcleanup() method I haven't written anything.

I want application to be still running once all the test method of the codedUI are completed running.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ApplicationUnderTest is specific to the test run, and by definition will close at the completion of the run.  What are your reasons for keeping it open between runs?

Comment: there is a  requirement where I had to keep application running once test run is completed.

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that.  What benefit would that serve you, though?  Most of the time, keeping the application open between tests (i.e., open browser, test 1, test 2, test 3, close browser) provides the maximum benefit to ensure a fresh build of your application and prevents a stale environment.  So, what will you gain be keeping it open between test runs?

Comment: I understand the benefit of it. but right now we want application running once  test is completed. Is there any way of doing it,

Comment: there is a property CloseOnPlaybackCleanup under ApplicationUnderTest classs. saw that if we set CloseOnPlaybackCleanup to false. application wont be closed automatically. but this property doesn't work for me. i have set CloseOnPlaybackCleanup  to false but still vs2013 closes the application.

Comment: CloseOnPlaybackCleanup works fine for Web Based application. are you referring to any desktop application ?

Comment: Yes its desktop application. but i tired with browser but still coded ui was closing the browser once test is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CloseOnPlayback** on the **ApplicationUnderTest** or **BrowserWindow** class, but this will only keep the application open during the test run. The moment all test methods in the test class have been executed the playback engine will still cleanup any instance created during the test. So between all test methods in the test class the application will be kept open, when all tests completed everything will be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

Run the application from the `[ClassInitialize]` or the `[AssemblyInitialize]` methods, but do not use Coded UI's methods to start it. This is because Coded UI keeps track of started applications so it can close them at the end of the test run. Instead use one of the other Windows process start methods, the `ProcessStartInfo` and `Process` classes, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(v=vs.110).aspx), may be suitable.

The question does not say what should happen if the tests are started when the application is already running. So perhaps the `[ClassInitialize]` or the `[AssemblyInitialize]` method should check whether the application is already active before running it, or perhaps the application should ignore or reject attempts to start it when it is already running.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on this? I have tried using `Process` rather than `ApplicationUnderTest` and then tried initialising this in a method that has the `[ClassInitialize]` attribute but it still closes the app when the tests are done.

Comment: @ChrisProsser It seems like a bug with 2013. In VS 2010 an application started with `Process.Start` would stay open upon completion of the test. With 2013 the application is killed after the test is complete. This answer *does not work* with 2013. I'm still trying to find a workaround...